# How to install Cent OS alongside Linux Mint?

Tags: centos, dual-boot

I am using Linux Mint 17.3 now and I want to install CentOS 7 alongside Linux Mint which I can choose when booting. How can I do dual boot from these distributions?

Comment: 1. Why do you want two Linux distributions one alongside others? 2. Isn't virtualization a more viable solution? 3. If you really want to, use either one's grub and it will detect the other OS and allow you to boot it.

Comment: No. I am going to prepare for RHCSA and I need a virtualization on CentOS . Also I don't want to remove my Mint.

Comment: It is impossible virtualization inside of Virtual Machine. Therefore I need it.

Comment: You just install the new system. What exactly is the issue here? There's nothing special about these two, you can install both just like you would for any other operating system. Have you read any information about dual booting? Which part of it is giving you trouble?

Comment: So you have a VM with Mint and you want CentOS on the same VM? Why not create a new VM?

Comment: @schaiba no. The OP has a regular system with Mint installed and now wants to add another OS to it. Virtualization is one option but there are perfectly good reasons to want to have multiple OSs on the same machine. There is not VM involved anywhere here and no reason for one, the OP just wants to install a new OS.

Comment: @terdon perhaps I misunderstood. He said "It is impossible virtualization inside of Virtual Machine. Therefore I need it."

Comment: @schaiba yes, but that's because you suggested virtualization as an alternative. I think the OP wants to eventually install a VM on a CentOS system. Therefore, they can't install a CentOS VM on the Mint host and then another VM on the already virtualized CentOS guest. Instead, they need a native CentOS installation. In any case, all of this is beside the point. The question is simply asking how to install Mint and CentOS on the same machine in parallel, *without* a VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install CentOS as usually , Reboot into Linux mint and run the following command:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

The `grub.cfg` will be updated and a new entry will be added automatically to GRUB menu

Comment: Why? The CentOS grub should have detected the Mint install anyway. Why re-run it?

Comment: @terdon Recently i have installed opensuse , Freebsd and Remixos  alongside Debian , the two last OS can't be detected after adding two new entry to my `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` until i have regenerate the `grub.cfg` from debian

Comment: @GAD3R no, the last two probably won't since they probably don't install their own bootloader unless told to. Most Linux distros do so though and the ones here use grub by default, so this shouldn't be necessary. CentOS should install its own grub and detect the other systems. Of course, *should* is not always *will*, but still. . .